# Prove $f(x)$ can reach its minimum value over $(a,+\infty).$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, maxima-minima

## Problem

If $f(x)$ is continuous over $(a,+\infty)$, and $\lim\limits_{x \to a+}f(x)=+\infty,$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty,$ then $f(x)$ can reach its minimum value over $(a,+\infty)$.

**This is my proof, which is written in Chinese. If necessary, I'm willing to translate it into English. But I hope to see your solutions.Thank you all!**

[image]

Comment: It not only can, it will

Comment: Have you tried to solve some of the problem yourself?

Comment: I did it. Now what?

Comment: Look up the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Looks good to me: You reduced the problem to a compact interval